# Theta series analogues for higher degree forms

Tags: nt.number-theory, cv.complex-variables, analytic-number-theory, modular-forms

It is simple to see that the following series converges absolutely and uniformly on $\mathcal{H}$ for all k positive:

$F_{2k}(z) = \sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} q^{n^{2k}}$

And this series being a generating function for higher degree forms is like a theta series analogue. But because the Fourier transform of the said function is not so nicely behaved ( the best I could compute required some very bad hyper geometric series), we do not get a ‘Modular form’ like symmetry.

So instead of using the Fourier transform, and then the poisson summation formula to get a symmetry on the Fourier series, is it possible to use some other integral transform, and then use the corresponding eigenfunction series based on that transform to get a ‘nice’ generating function with some transformation properties?

If not, is it possible to study the obstructions that one faces when trying to find the symmetries of a generating function like that?

(p.s. this question arose from a comment by D. Zagier in one of his lectures that every generating function is in some or the other form related to some Modular form, but I suppose we’ll need something more general than just Modular forms to study such functions)

Comment: I would be surprised if anything interesting about your general $F_{2k}$ is known. The comment of Zagier should be read under certain context, e.g. what did he mean by "every generating function"? I guess what he had in mind was a big picture of Langlands program.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to follow the standard theta argument for general $k$, to get a series expansion, except not one that relates the function to itself.

Consider
$$G_{2k}(z) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} e^{-n^{2k} z}$$
Take the Mellin transform of both sides
$$\int_0^\infty G_{2k}(z)z^{s-1}dz = \Gamma(s) \zeta(2ks)$$
Replace $z$ with $1/z$, and $s$ with $-s$
$$\int_0^\infty G_{2k}(1/z)z^{s-1}dz = \Gamma(-s) \zeta(-2ks))$$
Substituting in the functional equation for $\zeta(s)$ and expand both $\zeta$ and $\sin$ as a sum:
$$= \Gamma(-s)\Gamma(1+ks) (2\pi)^{-ks} (i^{ks}-i^{-ks}) \zeta(1+ks)$$
Thus, expanding out $\zeta$ as a sum and taking the inverse Mellin transform, you express $G_{2k}(z)$ as a sum over integers of a function that is an inverse mellin transform of a gamma function production (ie: a Meijer G-function).

When $k=1/2$ the function summed is basically $1/(1-z)$ giving you the expansion of $1/(e^z-1)$ in terms of its poles.  When $k=1$ the function summed is $e^{-z^2}$ giving you the functional equation.  For other $k$ the function is a hypergemetric function satisfying some nice properties, but not referring back to the original function.  There are some nice uses of these sums in [proving that functional equations cannot have degree strictly between 1 and 2](https://annals.math.princeton.edu/wp-content/uploads/annals-v173-n3-p04-p.pdf)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I’d reached the same conclusion that the hypergeometric series would not refer back to itself, that is why I was wondering if the approach of using the Mellin transform is not the answer to this sort of a series?